# XSL multiple replace in tranform string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to transform attributes to node and replace values to correct one. transforming and join works well but I can't figure out how to replace tranformed data. I tried `choose` and loop through attributes without any result.

Here is source XML

```
<cats>
  <cat id="11">Foo 1</cat>
  <cat id="12">Foo 2</cat>
</cats>
```

My XLS - this part works

```
<xsl:template match="cats">
    <cat-id>
       <xsl:value-of select="string-join(cat/@id, ',')" />
     </cat-id>
</xsl:template>
```

Replacement table `11 => 24, 12 => 75, 13 => 145 ...`

Result I want to achieve

```
<cat-id>24,75</cat-id>
```

Comment: You have tagged this as XSLT1.0 but `string-join()` requires XSLT 2.0. If the above works for you, then you must be using an XSLT 2.0 processor. -- Also, where do you want to keep the replacement table? Can it be hard-coded in the XSLT stylesheet?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.. I testing it in with Saxon 9.8 and I did't realize that I have xsltproc on server (I didn't run on server yet). Thank you for noticing it.

Comment: So are you still looking for an XSLT 1.0 solution?

Comment: Yes, it will be best for me, otherwise I have to install some new xls processor on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that maps each id attribute value to its replacement, in XSLT 3 (supported since 2017 by Saxon 9.8 and later and Altova 2017 and later) you can use a `map` as a function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="replacement-map" as="map(xs:integer, xs:integer)" select="map { 11 : 24, 12 : 75, 13 : 145 }"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="cats">
        <cat-id>
           <xsl:value-of select="cat/@id/$replacement-map(xs:integer(.))" separator="," />
         </cat-id>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNs

In XSLT 2 you could use an XML structure to represent your replacement table/map and use a key to find the replacement for an attribute value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="replacement-map">
        <value key="11">24</value>
        <value key="12">75</value>
        <value key="13">145</value>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:key name="rep" match="value" use="@key"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="cats">
        <cat-id>
           <xsl:value-of select="cat/@id/key('rep', ., $replacement-map)" separator="," />
         </cat-id>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNs/1

Finally in XSLT 1, as the `key` function doesn't have a third parameter to change the context doc, you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl msxml"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="replacement-map-rtf">
    <value key="11">24</value>
    <value key="12">75</value>
    <value key="13">145</value>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="replacement-map" select="exsl:node-set($replacement-map-rtf)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="rep" match="value" use="@key"/>

  <xsl:template match="cats">
      <cat-id>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="cat/@id"/>
      </cat-id>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cat/@id">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
      <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$replacement-map">
          <xsl:value-of select="key('rep', $this)"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNs/2

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in **XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<my:replacement-map>
    <value key="11">24</value>
    <value key="12">75</value>
    <value key="13">145</value>
</my:replacement-map>

<xsl:template match="cats">
    <cat-id>
        <xsl:for-each select="cat">
            <xsl:value-of select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:replacement-map/value[@key=current()/@id]" />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </cat-id>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you have many values, this could be made a bit more efficient by using a key. But pointing a key to a different document (the XSLT stylesheet itself, in this case) is awkward in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried your solution in fiddle and I got only <cat-id>,</cat-id>

Comment: @Destrosvet It will not work in an online test tool, because of the reference to the XSLT document - which doesn't really exist.